# How to alter structure of JSON file to create nesting

Tags: json, database, mongodb

How do you alter the JSON file either directly or within mongoDB to create nesting?

For example:
If the database was

```
Country - Date - Stock Market Open
A - Date 1 - Yes
A - Date 2 - Yes
A - Date 3 - No
B - Date 1 - No
B - Date 2 - Yes
B - Date 3 - Yes
```

I would like to nest it to show

```
country A {
date 1 {stock market open: yes}
date 2 { stock market open: yes}
date 3 { stock market open: no}
}
country B {
date 1 {stock market open: no}
date 2 { stock market open: yes}
date 3 { stock market open: yes}
}
```

by the country to create a nested array. Any other ways to alter the Json file can also be used.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What does your initial JSON file look like, or what does it look like in MongoDB? That first bit of code isn't JSON.